# SharePoint 2010: Create a compilation email from multiple items

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, javascript, designer-workflow

First of all, the tools I have available to me are SharePoint Designer and InfoPath, and I am much more comfortable in the former than the latter.

I have a request to create a solution to facilitate communication from my team to related teams. What they would like to do is have program managers enter their weekly updates, then have an email generated that would pull all of these together, which would then be reviewed by the team lead before going out to the other teams.  The next week, the PMs would enter new updates, and a new email would be generated using those updates, and so on and so forth.

The thought that occurred to me first was some sort of workflow on a timer that would send out weekly, but I don't know how it would pull in data from multiple items.

Has anyone implemented something like this?

Answer (score 0):

How about building a custom view of the Source (Submissions) list with SharePoint Designer and/or adding a javascript (load-script or button) somewhere to assemble all current items' text to a single item in another Target (Compilations) list? Then the lead would perform all reviews and then hit the button as soon as all submissions have been prepared. No need for workflow other than sending the resultant message.

If you really had to process item collections in workflow, you'd require custom workflow activities or extensions to the engine such as Nintex/Datapolis/K2.

Comment: So if I'm understanding the suggestion correctly, the button would run a script using something like the SOAP web services to read and write to the lists, then when it's done a workflow would run to send the email?

Comment: You got me right.